# How to Tweak a Jquery Image Transitions

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a jquery plugin that I am using on a wordpress site. It is 3 background images on the home page that transition between one another. The problem is that it is not a smooth transition but rather an abrupt transition. Not good looking.  Here is the code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {  
    var currentBackground = 0;
    var backgrounds = [];
        backgrounds[0] = 'http://soloveracruzesbello.mx/wp-content/uploads/img/soloveracruz/sites/7/2016/02/solo-veracruz-es-bello.jpg';
        backgrounds[1] = 'http://soloveracruzesbello.mx/wp-content/uploads/img/soloveracruz/sites/7/2016/02/solo-veracruz-es-bello-4.jpg';
        backgrounds[2] = 'http://soloveracruzesbello.mx/wp-content/uploads/img/soloveracruz/sites/7/2016/02/solo-veracruz-es-bello-5.jpg';

    function changeBackground() {
        currentBackground++;
        if(currentBackground > 2) currentBackground = 0;

        $('#elheader').fadeIn(2000,function() {
            $('#elheader').css({
                'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
            });
            $('#elheader').fadeIn(2000);
        });


        setTimeout(changeBackground, 3000);
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        setTimeout(changeBackground, 3000);        
    });
});
```

I have been fiddling with the the setting as in slideUp, slideDown, fadeIn, fadeOut but I cant get them images to transition smoothly.  Suggestions?

Comment: I've also fiddled with the setTimeout settings

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQueryUI you can do something like the following:

Live Example: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/NNKEOw

JQuery/JQueryUI:

```
$('#elheader').fadeIn({

  duration: 2000, 
  easing: "linear"    

});
```

Here is a link to some additional easing functions you can try out,
https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Answer (score 1):

Animating with javascript is not the best idea. Consider using CSS.
You can achieve fade effect with animating opacity.

```
.someClass{
    transition: all .5s;
    opacity:0;
}
```

And [here](http://codepen.io/frontendguy/pen/reBQdQ) you can see it in action. Furthermore you can replace js call to swap classes with keyframe animations.

Comment: @Stiliyan This made the transition look much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The transitions appear abrupt because you are changing the `background-image` of the same `#elheader` element. Also, notice that you only `fadeIn` the header without calling `fadeOut`, so the header remains at full opacity after the first `fadeIn`.

The simplest way to create smooth transitions between images, without significant modification to your code is to add a [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) on the header's `background-image` like so:

```
#elheader {
    transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also place each of your backgrounds into individual elements - and cycle through them, fade them in and out.

Comment: background-image is not animatable property according to specs https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties

Comment: That's correct - it's not part of the formal specification - but it is supported by modern browsers, with the exception of IE9.